# ValueError on KNN in Python

Tags: python, data-science, knn

Everything in my code is working well, until I try to use the KNN algorithm to predict the quality of wine using its attributes. This is my first time trying this code for KNN.

this part is giving me errors

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=0)
classifier.fit(wine_train[X], y_train)
```

Error location:

```
      1 from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
      2 classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=0)
----> 3 classifier.fit(wine_train[X], y_train)


File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:979, in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    962     raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
    964 X = check_array(
    965     X,
    966     accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
   (...)
    976     estimator=estimator,
    977 )
--> 979 y = _check_y(y, multi_output=multi_output, y_numeric=y_numeric)
    981 check_consistent_length(X, y)
    983 return X, y

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:989, in _check_y(y, multi_output, y_numeric)
    987 """Isolated part of check_X_y dedicated to y validation"""
    988 if multi_output:
--> 989     y = check_array(
    990         y, accept_sparse="csr", force_all_finite=True, ensure_2d=False, dtype=None
    991     )
    992 else:
    993     y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:800, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    794         raise ValueError(
    795             "Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
    796             % (array.ndim, estimator_name)
    797         )
    799     if force_all_finite:
--> 800         _assert_all_finite(array, allow_nan=force_all_finite == "allow-nan")
    802 if ensure_min_samples > 0:
    803     n_samples = _num_samples(array)

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py:122, in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype)
    120 elif X.dtype == np.dtype("object") and not allow_nan:
    121     if _object_dtype_isnan(X).any():
--> 122         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN")

ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of your features and target data?

Comment: wine_data_all,columns=['fixed acidity', 'volatile acidity', 'citric acid', 'residual sugar', 'chlorides', 'free sulfur dioxide', 'total sulfur dioxide', 'density', 'pH', 'sulphates', 'alcohol', 'quality]

fixed acidity volatile acidity citric acid residual sugar chlorides free sulfur dioxide total sulfur dioxide density pH sulphates alcohol
fixed acidity 1.000000 0.219008 0.324436 -0.111981 0.298195 -0.282735 -0.329054 0.458910 -0.252700 0.299568 -0.095452
volatile acidity 0.219008 1.000000 -0.377981 -0.196011

Comment: Its telling you that the number of rows for wine_train[X] and y_train are not equal. Either you are using a different dataset or didn't filter your data correctly.

Comment: Thanks @March_G - I corrected that but there is still an error. 
ValueError: Input contains NaN
Although I checked for Null and there weren't any.

Comment: Thanks @March_G - I corrected that but there is still an error. 
ValueError: Input contains NaN
When I checked the variables wine_train, wine_test, y_train and y_test, the latter 2 variables contain null values.
```y_train.isnull().values.any()``` returns True
```y_test.isnull().values.any()``` returns True

Comment: @rfurtado It's easy to fix, you could either use fillna() to fill missing values e.g. with median y_train.fillna(y_train.median()) or dropna() to drop rows with missing values. If you want to drop, do this before you split features and target, to avoid missmatches between shapes or features and targets or use isna() of y_train or y_target.